# disable li and don't allow to click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i use twitter bootstrap and jquery.

Depending of a variable, i would like to disable and remove the possibility to click

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
   <li id="member" role="presentation" data-toggle="tab" class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></span> Membres</a></li>
   <li id="subscription" role="presentation" data-toggle="tab"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bed"></span> Abonnements</a></li>
</ul>
```

i tried this code

```
if (role != "ROLE_ADMIN") {
  $('#subscription').addClass("disabled").find("a").attr("onclick", "return false;");
  $('#report').addClass("disabled").find("a").attr("onclick", "return false;");
  $('#user').addClass("disabled").find("a").attr("onclick", "return false;");
  $('#setup').addClass("disabled").find("a").attr("onclick", "return false;");
} else {
    $("#subscription").removeClass("disabled").find("a").removeAttr("onclick");
    $("#report").removeClass("disabled").find("a").removeAttr("onclick");
    $("#user").removeClass("disabled").find("a").removeAttr("onclick");
    $("#setup").removeClass("disabled").find("a").removeAttr("onclick");
}
```

li is disabled, but i can click on it...

Edit

```
$('#user').prop('onclick',null).off('click');
```

seem to do the job

Answer (score 11):

Add some styles to your disabled class like

```
.disabled{
    pointer-events:none;
    opacity:0.7;
}
```

Comment: I used this method and it worked well, however I defined it this way `li .disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
`. It seemed safer to scope it to just the li tag for now.

Comment: I used this to disable click event from library (Clarity), all other methods did not work. Thx :)

Answer (score 2):

just because it appears disabled does not necessarily mean it is disabled. you will have to listen to events and prevent their default action to disable them.

or, using CSS you can use `pointer-events: none;`

Comment: it should be noted, too, that this code is not secure, i can just enable the buttons myself through the developer tools, so make sure you have server-side validation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simplified a lot. If you want to remove the 'clickable' styles of your links, try this:

#### js

```
if (role != "ROLE_ADMIN") {
  $('#subscription, #report, #user, #setup')
      .addClass("disabled")
      .find("a").prop("disabled", true);
} else {
   $('#subscription, #report, #user, #setup')
      .removeClass("disabled")
      .find("a").prop("disabled", false); 
}
```

#### css

```
.disabled a {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: grey;
}
```

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q2k1yawh/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `disabled` class to your element and then add this JS script to prevent clicking on disabled elements :

```
    $('a').click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```